# Themify-icons dont apper in my newly created WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, html, themes

The style.css is importing themify.icons.css and themify.icons is referencing to a folder in my theme which has the fonts files, I have tried to change the paths in both CSS but still with no luck.

I can provide you the URL (http://duniatourssafaris.com) plus some column in (http://duniatourssafaris.com/mountain-trekking/) is breaking as I have gone through the code but didn't figure out I have used column 4 for the tabs.

Comment: External resources can change. Please paste any relevant code into the question.

Comment: Just looked at your site. The CSS file references all appear to be pointing to the correct locations for the fonts. What's the issue?

Comment: Just noticed that you're getting some server permissions issue with your fonts when looking in the Chrome developer console:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) themify9f24.ttf` and `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Comment: This needs an [mcve] to be answerable, and the information needs to be in the question itself. This is because once your website is fixed, the question will not reflect the situation that required repair, and at that point, the question would need to be deleted. That's not fair on people who help, as their answers would be deleted too. Would you edit your question please?